# What cars can you get for free with car mastery perks?

Tags: forza-horizon-4

In Forza Horizon 4 you can earn skill points, which you can spend later to unlock *car mastery* perks and get some bonuses. Each car model has its own unique perk progression tree.

The rarest bonus you can unlock is getting a brand new car. So far, I have found 6 models with this perk:

| Car with the mastery perk | Skill points cost | Car that you get for free |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1954 Mercedes-Benz 300 SL coupé | 20 | 2009 Mercedes-Benz SL 65 AMG black series Forza edition |
| 1957 Maserati 300 S | 15 | 2004 Maserati MC12 Forza edition |
| 1967 Lamborghini Miura P400 | 30 | 2008 Lamborghini Reventón Forza edition |
| 1998 Nissan R390 | 25 | 1995 Nissan NISMO GT-R LM Forza edition |
| 2005 TVR Sagaris | 99 | 2005 TVR Sagaris Forza edition |
| Quartz Regalia | 99 | Quartz Regalia Type-D |

**Are there any more?**

I've tried googling it, but the only links I've found ([1](https://forums.forzamotorsport.net/turn10_postst130156_Car-Mastery-and-Perks.aspx), [2](https://www.reddit.com/r/forza/comments/9o59h7/fe_forza_edition_car_list_unlocked_with_perks/), [3](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l232oW9tvOxXmYNb610_JhECBWCD5HtXeK8k9Juo_tw/htmlview)) are from 3 years ago, and the game has kept evolving since then. For example none of these links include the Quartz Regalia (yes, the car from Final Fantasy) because it was added later to the game.

I could try checking the cars myself, but there are 752 different models, and it takes at least a minute to check each one. Plus you can only check a car if you own it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've checked the perks progression tree for *almost* every car in the game and haven't found any more with the "free car" perk. So, **the complete list is as follows**:

| Car | Autoshow price | Points | Car that you get for free |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1967 Lamborghini Miura P400 | 1.000.000 CR | 30 | 2008 Lamborghini Reventón Forza edition |
| 1957 Maserati 300 S | 6.000.000 CR | 15 | 2004 Maserati MC12 Forza edition |
| 1954 Mercedes-Benz 300 SL coupé | 1.200.000 CR | 20 | 2009 Mercedes-Benz SL 65 AMG black series Forza edition |
| 1998 Nissan R390 | 730.000 CR | 25 | 1995 Nissan NISMO GT-R LM Forza edition |
| Quartz Regalia | Not sold | 99 | Quartz Regalia Type-D |
| 2005 TVR Sagaris | 86.000 CR | 99 | 2005 TVR Sagaris Forza edition |

I've been unable to check out 9 of the 752 available cars:

- 2017 Chevrolet Camaro ZL1 preorder car
- 2017 Ford Focus RS preorder car
- 1957 Hot Wheels Studebaker Golden Hawk 'dream roadster' (DLC)
- 1969 Hot Wheels International-Harvester Loadstar CO-1600 (DLC)
- 1949 Hot Wheels Ford F-5 dually custom hot rod (DLC)
- 1957 Hot Wheels Nash metropolitan custom (DLC)
- 2018 Hot Wheels 2jetz (DLC)
- 1972 Hot Wheels Chevrolet Luv (DLC)
- 2018 McLaren 720S coupé preorder car

The "preorder" cars are no longer obtainable, unless you get *extremely* lucky in a wheelspin. The DLC cars are part of the Hot Wheels car pack, which isn't included in the base game, the expansions or the car pass, it must be purchased separatedly.

---

I have also compiled a list of other cars with the most rare and profitable perk bonuses:

| Car | Autoshow price | Points | Perk bonus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2014 Mercedes-Benz G 63 AMG 6x6 | Not sold | 25 | 6 wheelspins |
| 1985 Toyota Sprinter Trueno GT apex | Not sold | 5 | Super wheelspin |
| 1998 Toyota Supra RZ | 250.000 CR | 10 | Super wheelspin |
| 2017 Mercedes-Benz E 350 D 4matic all-terrain "Project E-AT" | Not sold | 10 | 250.000 CR |
| 1966 MG MGB GT | Not sold | 5 + 10 | 100.000 + 200.000 CR |
| 2007 Alfa Romeo 8C Competizione | 300.000 CR | 10 | 300.000 CR |
| 2016 Audi R8 V10 plus | 242.000 CR | 10 | 300.000 CR |
| 2013 Caterham Superlight R500 Forza edition | Not sold | 10 | 300.000 CR |
| 1969 Ford Mustang Boss 302 | Not sold | 10 | 300.000 CR |
| 1995 Formula drift #118 Nissan 240SX | 300.000 CR | 10 | 300.000 CR |
| 2015 Formula drift #13 Ford Mustang | 300.000 CR | 10 | 300.000 CR |
| 1996 Formula drift #232 Nissan 240SX | 300.000 CR | 10 | 300.000 CR |
| 2006 Formula drift #43 Dodge Viper SRT10 | 300.000 CR | 10 | 300.000 CR |
| 2016 Formula drift #530 HSV Maloo Gen-F | 300.000 CR | 10 | 300.000 CR |
| 1997 Formula drift #777 Nissan 240SX | 300.000 CR | 10 | 300.000 CR |
| 1989 Formula drift #98 BMW 325i | 300.000 CR | 10 | 300.000 CR |
| 2005 Honda NSX-R | Not sold | 10 | 300.000 CR |
| 2017 Hoonigan Gymkhana 10 Ford Fiesta | Not sold | 10 | 300.000 CR |
| 1991 Hoonigan Rauh-Welt Begriff Porsche 911 turbo | Not sold | 10 | 300.000 CR |
| 2015 Jaguar XKR-S GT | Not sold | 10 | 300.000 CR |
| 2010 Lamborghini Murciélago LP 670-4 SV | 500.000 CR | 10 | 300.000 CR |
| 2009 Mercedes-Benz SL 65 AMG black series | 210.000 CR | 10 | 300.000 CR |
| 2009 Mercedes-Benz SL 65 AMG black series Forza edition | Not sold | 10 | 300.000 CR |
| 1969 Nissan Fairlady Z 432 | 150.000 CR | 10 | 300.000 CR |
| 1973 Nissan Skyline H/T 2000GT-R | 170.000 CR | 10 | 300.000 CR |
| 2018 Porsche 911 GT2 RS | 315.000 CR | 10 | 300.000 CR |
| 2012 Porsche 911 GT3 RS 4.0 | 200.000 CR | 10 | 300.000 CR |
| 2016 Porsche 911 GT3 RS preorder car | Not sold | 10 | 300.000 CR |
| 1982 Porsche 911 turbo 3.3 | 150.000 CR | 10 | 300.000 CR |
| 1970 Porsche 914/6 | Not sold | 10 | 300.000 CR |
| 2004 Saleen S7 | 388.000 CR | 10 | 300.000 CR |
| 1969 Toyota 2000GT | Not sold | 10 | 300.000 CR |

The "6 wheelspins" perk in the *Mercedes-Benz G 63* has exactly the same icon than the regular wheelspin perk, I almost didn't notice it. There could be other cars that I've missed with that perk, however it's unlikely, considering it seems to be a joke on the fact that the car has 6 wheels. I've checked the *Hennessey Velociraptor 6x6*, which is the only other 6-wheeled car, but it doesn't have it.